# How to display Google Map zoom level in Div

Tags: javascript, geocoding

How to display google Map zoom level inside Div like a lable.

Something like in the Image

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
        function myMap() {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(56.1304, -106.3468);
            var mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 6, scrollwheel: true, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
         
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
```

```html
<div style="padding: 0px; padding-top:2px; padding-right:2px; width:25px; height: 25px; background-color: #fff; font-size:18px; border: solid 1px #777; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; font-weight:bold;">
    display zoom level here
</div>
```

Comment: The Map object has a [getZoom()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.getZoom) function you can use to get the current zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code as described on the [Google Maps Javascript API Documentation Page (Events)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events). Add a zoom change listener to the map and set the div content to the new zoom on each change.

```
<div id="zoom"></div>

map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log('Zoom: ' + currentZoom);
    //You can now set the value to the div content
    document.getElementById("zoom").innerHTML = currentZoom;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But I have One more issue. It does not show the zoom level on page load. it shows only on zoom changed.

Comment: I suggest you pass the initial zoom you initialized the map with to the div on page load or right after initiializing the map do `document.getElementById("zoom").innerHTML = map.getZoom();` so that on page load you have the initial zoom set to the div.